# Prestashop : Remove Lastname Field Rules Validation From B.O

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, prestashop-helper-classes

I am trying to remove **rules validation** for **customer's Lastname** field..

I have succeed to do it in the front page for customer registration by editing Classes/Customer.php file like this:

`'lastname' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCustomerName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),`

to :

`'lastname' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAnything', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),`

I have simply used **isAnything** in validation.

But that's not working in the **Backoffice**, so i can't edit customers from BO.

Can't find what **file** to change exactly.

I am using **Prestashop V1.7.6.8.**
Need help please. Thanks

Comment: What is "success in front and fail in back" for you?

Comment: that means the customer is allowed to submit any character in "lastname" field but i still can't create or modify a customer from Backoffice because of field lastname validation. For example i can't put numbers in that field.

Comment: @Fran Cerezo ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must modify two methods in two files.

src/Core/ConstraintValidator/CustomerNameValidator.php, method isNameValid

```
private function isNameValid($name)
{
    return true; // Here true or your own validation.
    // Down the original code.
    $pattern = $this->characterCleaner->cleanNonUnicodeSupport(self::PATTERN_NAME);

    return (bool) preg_match($pattern, $name);
}
```

src/Core/Domain/Customer/ValueObject/LastName.php, method assertLastNameIsValid

```
private function assertLastNameIsValid($lastName)
{
    return true; // Here true or your own validation.
    // Down the original code.
    $matchesLastNamePattern = preg_match('/^[^0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:¤|]*$/u', stripslashes($lastName));

    if (!$matchesLastNamePattern) {
        throw new CustomerConstraintException(sprintf('Customer last name %s is invalid', var_export($lastName, true)), CustomerConstraintException::INVALID_LAST_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i am looking for, thank you very much @Fran Cerezo

Comment: Glad to help you @Wajdi :)